# Strange push notification behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm dealing with the apple push notifications.
First point: they're working, and that's fine :) (I followed this tutorial as kikstart: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

Second point: when I push a notification from the server, my phone is receiving an alert (I'm talking when the app isn't running) for each notification I didn't 'open'.
Is this a default behaviour?

If this is not a default behaviuor I'll add some code and particulars about all the system I'm working with, but before writing tons of information I would like to understand if this behaviour is a bug.

Thanks!

Comment: One of the big selling points to push notifications is that the app doesn't have to be running. The server that pushes the notification is looking to give important information to the app (& user).

Comment: Of course! Maybe I didn't explain myself: I push a notification, the phone receives one notification (rings one let's say). I don't open the app, I push a second notification, the phone receives two notifications (rings two times). Is this right?

Comment: So after the first notification it rings once and the second is received it rings twice in addition to the first?

Comment: Exactly. And the notification title is the one of the first push.